# How to change control from keyboard to Xbox controller on Batman Arkham City for PC

Tags: pc, controllers, batman-arkham-city

Do I have to change any property from "true" to "false" in game file, or the game will detect if the controller is connected?

Answer (score 3):

A standard wired Xbox 360 pad does this its self normally if not there should be a 'Use controller' Setting in the player options which enables this & picks the pad up.

Answer (score 2):

If you plug in a controller, it should automatically detect it (it did for me, with a wired Xbox 360 controller).

Answer (score 1):

Any controller which uses XInput should automatically be detected by the game and will trigger the Xbox 360 controller layout, although you may need to restart the game if you attempt to plug it in while in-game.

Answer (score 0):

If you have controller issues honestly, what I did, XPadder. I have a cheap gigaware controller that I just set keys to buttons and it works. Its worked for every game I have played. Dead Island: Riptide, Batman Arkham Origins, Grand theft auto, killing floor, and others I have.

Comment: We suggest that **any question** should be asked **at arqade**.

Answer (score 0):

After starting the game, press any button in the controller. It will be activated.